# ngRepeat doesn't $compile directives correctly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of items [Expression, Expression,....] and I add/remove Expression's from the array, but ngRepeat doesn't $compile the directive correctly.

What could be the reason for it?

One of the solutions is, that I have a separate array of Expressions, and I modify that one, and every time it changes I reset the "expressions" to [] and set the new array, but when doing this there is blinking of the UI elements (first digest to [] and then timeout(expressions = new array)).

```js
// Main
scope.list = [Expressions.new(), Expressions.new()];


//constructor Expressions

function Expressions(){};
Expression.prototype = {
  id: 'generated',
  list: [
    Expression.new(), Expression.new(),... 
  ]
};


//constructor Expression

function Expression(){};
Expression.prototype = {
  id: 'generated',
  val: ''
};
```

```html
<!-- Main Usage -->
<div ng-repeat="expressions in list track by $index" dir-expressions x-attrs="expressions"></div>

<!-- Expressions directive -->
<div class="Expressions_Content">
  <ul ng-sortable="attrs.sortable">
    <li ng-repeat="expression in attrs.items track by $index">
      <div dir-expression x-attrs="expression"></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div> 


<!-- Expression directive -->
<div>{{Value}}</div>
```

It is a complex situation, so I will just put some code snippets in the example.

Comment: some more code is required

Comment: This should work. Problem is somewhere else. Show us the rest of the code please.

Comment: this is a complex situation, if I make a video with logs, will that help? If not I will add more code later today.

Comment: added some code, update of lists happen on expressions.

Comment: not enough code posted to reproduce your problem.  what do the directives look like, beyond their templates?

Comment: Instead of `track by $index` have you tried tracking by the Expression.id or some other property of the items being repeated? It's [discussed in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates). The suggested syntax would be: `ng-repeat="expression in attrs.items track by expression.id"`

Comment: dude that solved it, track by expression.id, thx, you are totally awesome. I thought that if I use $index there, that it should work, but now that I think about it, it is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

As Sunil D pointed out, use track by expression.id instead of $index.